# anonymous delegate hashCode

Tags: c#, caching, delegates

I thought about creating some cache helper that gets a `Func<T>` (or some delegate for .Net2.0)
calculates its hash code (or any other unique string) and if this has code doesn't exist adds it to the cache.

Is that possible at all? 
Does this approach make sense at all?

How can I tell the difference between:

```
GetCache(() => string.Format("{0}", 1));
```

And

```
GetCache(() => string.Format("{0}", 2))
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* use hash codes to determine uniqueness. That's not what they're there for.

In your example, the two lambda expressions will end up creating separate methods for the delegates... but it's quite possible (not guaranteed) that they'd do this *anyway* even if the code inside was exactly the same. In other words, I think the whole caching idea is fundamentally not going to work in the way that you're expecting it to.

Comment: 10x for the answer. Are you saying this doesn't make sense at all? or can I may be implement it in some different way?

Comment: @CD: It's not entirely clear whether you're caching the result of *executing* the delegate or something else... but basically I suspect you're going to run into problems if you try to just use the same lambda expression from multiple bits of code. Have you looked into using `Lazy<T>` instead (if you're using .NET 4)?

Comment: I'd like to cache the result of executing the delegate. This specific project is using .Net2.0, so using Lazy<T> can't help here. any idea?

Comment: @CD: I suggest you write your own equivalent of `Lazy<T>`, basically. You'd basically need "well-known" lazy evaluators, rather than specifying the lambda expressions at arbitrary places, which I *think* is what you were after before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your lambas may include captured variables from outside of their scope so e.g.

```
String.Format("{0}", i);
```

will evaluate differently depending on the value of I when it was captured. If it is worth while to do because the delegates that you are invoking are expensive you probably need to build a higher level object that includes your methods and enough metadata to find them back.